# Cardova IOS 10. "Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown"

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad

I have two iOS app.
I received this error, when I try open another app, using `window.open(url)`. It stopped working on iOS 10, but working an early version (ex. 9.x).

```
url = "mySecondApp://#params";
```

In first app config: `<access origin="mySecondApp://*" launch-external="yes" />`

But I can open standard app (ex. `itms-apps:*`)

Answer (score 3):

Try updating your app's **Info.plist** by adding **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** key of type Array with an Item of type String that has 'mySecondApp' value in it. 
I found that I needed to whitelist custom URL schemes in order for my Cordova apps' links (that worked on iOS 8) to work on iOS 10.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Thanks you Nastassia,

I had as error: "failed to load webpage: url cannot be shown" for ionic setting in order to access extern app.

Nastassia's solution source code to add:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
   <string>ebizupv3doc</string>
</array>
```

Comment: What is `ebizupv3doc`? I personally know, but why you put this as a separate answer? Post it as a comment to above answer.